# AngularJS ng-repeat not updating properly when delete items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The problem that I'm facing is that I have a ng-repeat and when I delete an item by clicking a button with a function associated to delete items in array the ng-repeat not shows properly the actual array.

The array looks like:

```
['stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', ....]
```

What shows ng-repeat when I delete an item is the array without the last position although I deleted the first position. When I perform a console.log the array looks correct, the first position or x position was removed.

Comment: Can you show the code that does the deletion and the html fragment containing the ng-repeat?

Comment: @refrigerator No, it is an example only. I have an array of differents images(src).

Comment: @GruffBunny here you have the code: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qOppcM0J86YJcQ19wDXU?p=info)

Comment: Is Images an array or an object? The reason I ask is that the ng-repeat is treating it as an object and when you delete you treat it as an array (using splice)

Comment: @GruffBunny Images is an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the:

```
track by $index
```

Due to some duplicate images in the proofs I've been doing. I removed it and it works as expected.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I used it because angular was complaining about duplicates. To stop angular complaining about duplicates I used aron.duby's answer: instead of ['a', 'a','a'] I used [{'text':'a'}, {'text':'a'}] and got no more duplicates errors.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue, I eventually narrowed it down to having something to do with the angular not being notified that something changed. To work around this, try using $apply. So something like this:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
  // remove the item from the array 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

long answer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

short answer, switch your array to be:

```
[{label:'stuff'},...]
```

Comment: My array looks right now `[Object { label="xxx.jpg"}, Object { label="xxx.jpg"}, Object { label="xxx.jpg"}, Object { label="xxx.jpg"}]`but I'm getting the same results...